# Change homepage after dyno restart in PHP app

Tags: php, apache, heroku, openvbx

Each time the dyno restarts (after a new commit, for instance), all urls I enter are automatically rewritten to /index.php/install until I finish the installation procedure, which (as expected) flushes the database. I couldn't find where such behavior could be changed and it's a problem since it means that I can't do any change on the app without scrapping the database!

I'm not very familiar with either PHP or Apache. I assumed that Procfile and .httaccess might hold the key to my problem but I couldn't find in either a line that would implement a logic that would say: if I've just restarted, then root page should be install instead of login AND prevent any other page from opening.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd expect your database to get "flushed" or "scrapped" when you push a new version to Heroku. Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: It's the installation process (config/install/main.php) that flushes the database and that's normal. But this process is only supposed to be run once. My problem is that Heroku keeps launching it on each dyno restart.